# Json - Append Java object to existing Json file

Tags: java, json, libgdx

I'm in LibGDX and I've to save position of certain dots. I have a class like this:

```
public class DotPositions {
    private ArrayList<Vector2> position;
    private int numberofDots;
    private String levelName;
}
```

Then I convert an object of this class into json and save it in a file `position.json` using:

```
private ArrayList<Vector2> dotPosition = new ArrayList<>(); //this value is assigned elsewhere
private DotPositions positions;
positions.setNumberofDots(dotPosition.size());
positions.setLevelName("level_one");

Json json = new Json(JsonWriter.OutputType.json);
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("position.json");
file.writeString(json.prettyPrint(positions), false);
```

And as a result, I got a json like this:

```
{
"position": [
    {
        "x": 200,
        "y": 300
    },
    {
        "x": 250,
        "y": 500
    }
],
"numberofDots": 2,
"levelName": "level_one"
}
```

Now I want to add (append) dot positions of another level (say, Level 2) the same way to the same json file. I'm guessing it will be a json array but I don't know deep enough to make a statement. Anybody know how to convert another `DotPosition` object into json and append it to the previously saved json file?

---

**Edit:** I don't know enough about json so I could be wrong in the format, but the expected output is something like this:

```
{
"position": [
    {
        "x": 200,
        "y": 300
    },
    {
        "x": 250,
        "y": 500
    }
],
"numberofDots": 2,
"levelName": "level_one"
},
{
"position": [
    {
        "x": 100,
        "y": 100
    },
    {
        "x": 600,
        "y": 350
    }
],
"numberofDots": 2,
"levelName": "level_two"
}
```

Comment: Show an example of the expected output please.

Comment: @dambros I've edited the question description to include an example. Please check it.

Comment: The easiest way is to build a list of DotPositions and convert this list to JSON. The output will be a JSON array with the different levels as you want.

Comment: @dambros Thanks so much. Now I think about it, it seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: @dambros Hey can I ask you one more thing? Actually I'm only at the starting stage of my game. So this saving positions is kind of a prerequisite of development. I'm doing it by each level - save position of level 1, then quit the game, save position of level 2, quit the game. So this method you proposed won't work here as I have to quit the game before loading next level. Do you think there's a better option?

Comment: You can always save the current JSON to some file/db before quitting. When you start the next level, you simply load/parse the previous json, generate the new level and add it to the previous loaded json(which will parse to a list). Just keep doing and you will always have the complete info.

Answer (score 0):

As dambros said. Most generic (best) solution is to have List of DotPosition, working with it as with object and on end of your work save this list to file.
But if you only need append anything into file use "true" parameter in method writeString(). For more informations check this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#writing-to-a-file

Comment: Yes I think I'll go with @dambros solution. I don't exactly require the append option in `FileHandle`. It will be a more difficult path.